# Play .SWF files from internal storage in android webview in nexus 7 android

Tags: android, flash, android-webview, local-storage, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Cant play .swf(flash files) files from internal storage in android webview on jellybean installed devices (for eg:-nexus7)
but i can play .swf(flash files) on android honeycomb devices...
Also i figured this out as jellybean onwards android stopped supporting flash files plugin
and even adobe stopped developing for the same in android.

Here is some code snippets that i tried with no results----

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    String url =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/FolderName/Filename.swf";
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());//also tried WebViewClient
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.loadUrl(url);
```

only a small icon is shown at the centre of webview.
[Note- i have even tried to load using html file but nothing worked]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workable solution...dont know how feasible it is but this solution works for me
follow this steps..

```
Step1->Download flash player apk from this
```

[Link to download Flash Player apk](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html?PID=3640929)

```
Step2->After downloading go to settings--->security---->Check "Unkown sources option".

Step3->install the apk that you downloaded+

Now your webview code will work and .swf files can be played inside webview
```

[note-download flashplayer apk for android 4.0 devices for ics and above].

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

Android no longer supports Flash files.

Comment: i knew this but what is the alternative option to play .swf files?

Comment: HTML5/CSS/JavaScript or code an native application. The .swf will not work unless you find some third party library that can play them as if they were a normal view.

Comment: i already have a .swf file and i can play it on some applications from play store by just launching simple action.view intent. but i need to launch in webview or some other view if possible.also jelly bean already supports HTML5 then why should i write a code for it

Comment: If I knew I would have told you on the previous comment. You can try to find but I think it's unlikely to exist.